# How can I put PHP code inside JavaScript document.write

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, document.write

Hello can anyone please help me in fixing this code?

1st code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById("tester") != undefined)
{
    document.write('**2nd code should be here**');
}
else
{
    document.write('<img scr="./img.png" />');
}
</script>
```

2nd code

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); get_template_part('item-video');
endwhile; ?>
```

What I want to happen is to insert the 2nd code into the first code. But when I try to insert it, it gives me a blank page.

Comment: Why not print it directly to the body - without `document.write`?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I already tried that but it gives me blank page.

Comment: You should not mix PHP with JavaScript. Can't you do the `tester`-condition in PHP as well?

Comment: Then, something is wrong with your `the_post()` function. It's printing something with `print`, `echo`? Show us its content too.

Comment: @Bergi Idont know how to make a condition. Anyway I am trying this one http://erikswan.net/abp/

Comment: @Mia The problem is probably in the PHP code. You need to post the contents of the `item-video` template part, as that is probably where the error is.

Comment: This won't work because PHP is executed by the server and JS is executed by the client. When you open a PHP script in your browser, it doesn't download the script, but it's output. There's something called AJAX for this purpose.

Comment: Try it: Instead of print the output during the while, save it on a php variable and output it on the javascript "else" statement. I think that the problem can be an open quote.

Answer (score 0):

the biggest thing I've heard is that PHP is server side, while Javascript is client side. Therefore, changing the html page using document.write() isn't going to do anything unless you reload the page. I think you can circumvent this problem tho, using Ajax and the load() function.